# Migrate a SQL Server instance from one server to another

Tags: sql-server, aws

I have a database for my website running on AWS.  My web admin has given me access to the database, and I'd like to host and manage it on my own.  How do I migrate the SQL database from AWS to my own SQL server?

Comment: How large is the database?

Comment: @JasonB. 17.5 MB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you mean the Instance or the database, as your question is referring to both (as if they are one).

**If you're speaking of migrating a database from one server/instance to another:**
If you have access to the .mdb/.mdf files, I'd say copy it over to whichever the destination server is, then run SQL Server's Database Import/Restore functionality.

The option I'd prefer:
Using the "Copy Database" functionality, available by Right clicking the database name and selecting Tasks->Copy Database and following the wizard.

After this, you'll be able to use the Import/export data wizard to get the data replicated over.

**If you're speaking of migrating an entire instance:**
Not entirely sure I'd take that approach, as I like to do one database at a time when replicating/migrating.  This is because I've often run into issues and it's much easier to isolate when you take it one database at a time.

Comment: Thanks very much. This is exactly what I was looking for.  I have modified the question and omitted the word 'instance' for clarification.

Comment: Most welcome.  Glad that helped you.  I'm a long-time SQL Server Admin venturing into ORACLE, so I completely understand the slight confusion in terminology.  "Up is white, black is left" for me right now :)

Answer (score 2):

The database is 17.5mb, so quite small. I am assuming you can RDP onto the server in AWS, or have the ability to RDP? If so, then simply take a backup of the database, copy the backup down to your local machine, and then restore it locally.

Comment: Much safer option in my opinion. Detaching the datafiles is (almost) never a viable option for me. Also worth pointing out that users may need to be re-mapped on the destination server.

Comment: dwjv, good point about security.